# Implicit differentiation and the Folium of Descartes

Tags: differential-equations

Given the function (Folium of Descartes) $x^3 + y^3 = 3xy$, how would I find the equations for tangent and normal lines at the point $\left( \frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2} \right)$?

I know that I must use the `Dt` function, but how do I calculate the tangent and normal lines?

Also, how would I graph these lines using the `ContourPlot` function?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  Folium = Plot[y /. Solve[x^3 + y^3 == 3 x y, y], {x, -3, 3},
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{3/2, 3/2}]}]
```

[image]

Once you determine which of the three solution segments goes through $\{3/2, 3/2\}$ (it is the first) you find the derivative with respect to $x$.  You can either take the derivative with respect to $x$ for the first solution, or merely cut and paste it as follows and substitute the $x$ value $3/2$:

```
Re@N@Simplify@
    D[(2^(1/3) x)/(-x^3 + Sqrt[-4 x^3 + x^6])^(1/3) 
      + (-x^3 + Sqrt[-4 x^3 + x^6])^(1/3)/2^(1/3), x] /. x -> 3/2
```

(* -1 *)

So the tangent line is $y = -x + b$, where $b$ ensures the line goes through $\{3/2, 3/2\}$.  A simple `Solve` shows that $b = 3$.

Thus the tangent line can be plotted as:

```
mylinePlot = Plot[-x + 3, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red];

Show[Folium, myLine]
```

[image]

The perpendicular has slope $-1$ divided by the slope of the tangent, and thus the slope is $+1$ and its intercept must ensure the perpendicular line go through $\{3/2, 3/2\}$.  As before, a simple `Solve` reveals $b = 0$:

```
myPerp = Plot[x, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Green];

Show[Folium, myLine, myPerp, AspectRatio->1]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you!

Comment: @Dr.Tang  Please "accept" this answer by clicking on the check mark beneath the large number to the left of the answer.